# Iterate or count ArrayCollection from twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine, arraycollection

symfony 2.8

Ok, I have a Category entity which looks like this:

```
class Category
{

    // ... //
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Classified", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $classified;

    // ... // 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->classified = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

and the Classified entity looks like this:
Class Classified

```
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="classified")
     */
    private $category;
}
```

In my result.html.twig I called to render the controller like this:

```
{{ render(controller('ClassifiedBundle:Category:displayCategoryPanelList'))}}
```

which basically calls Category Controller

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function displayCategoryPanelListAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $categories = $em->getRepository('ClassifiedBundle:Category')
                    ->findAllOrderedByName();


        return $this->render('ClassifiedBundle:Front/Widgets:category-panel-list.html.twig',
            array(
                'categories'    => $categories
            ));
    }
}
```

which in turn calls the CategoryRepository for query:

```
class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c, cc')
            ->leftJoin('c.classified', 'cc')
            ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $query;
    }
}
```

which in the end is rendered to category-panel-list.html.twig:

```
<ul>
  {% for c in categories %}
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa {{ c.icon }}"></i>
        {{ c.name }} <span class="category-counter">{# COUNT SHOULD GO HERE#}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Now, all these work fine apart from the counting classified arraycollection part.  I have tried `{{ c.classified|length }}` but this gives a fatal error.

The dump looks good and I can see the entry for the classified collection, but just don't know how to count them.  Some categories have empty classified collection.
[image]

Comment: "I have tried {{ c.classified|length }} but this gives a fatal error." - What is the fatal error?

Answer (score 4):

`{{ c.classified|length }}` is applied to an array.

Your object `c.classified` is a `PersistCollection`, not an array.

You should use `{{ c.classified.count }}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try just using the doctrine method

```
{{ c.classified.count }}
```